# Apple TV/Internet line

Tags: wifi, appletv

I don't know if this is the place to ask by I'm trying to diagnose a problem with my Apple TV.

No matter what TV app I choose (BBC, Prime, Netflix etc) the program stops and I get a 'Something went wrong error', after a few minutes the program tends to start back up again, sometimes from where it left off and sometimes from the start (and we have to scan through to find where we were).

There tends to be a fairly consistent stop at between 6 and 8 minutes into each film/tv program as if the box hasn't buffered enough.

I'm trying to find out if this is an Apple TV problem or an ISP problem....is there any kind of log on my router that would let me know if there was a drop-out.

I run the Apple TV on wifi and on ethernet (to see if it makes a difference).

I have a few Raspberry Pi's set up - is there a python script I can run to log the internet connection?

I've tried a few different 'Speed test' type apps but get conflicting results.